# how to start executing code if one code is already executed

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection('users_donors').doc('users').collection('usersList').where('userType', '==', 'users').get().then(doc => {
  setupUI(user);
});

db.collection('users_donors').doc('donors').collection('donorsList').where('userType', '==', 'donors').get().then(doc => {
  setupUIDonor(user);
});
```

Comment: Do you mean about calling in chain:
1.db.collection('users_donors').doc('users').collection('usersList').where('userType', '==', 'users').get().then(doc => {
  setupUI(user);
}) and 
then when 1 Promise  will be completed/resolved
2. db.collection('users_donors').doc('donors').collection('donorsList').where('userType', '==', 'donors').get().then(doc => {
  setupUIDonor(user);
});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the second database call run *after* the first one completes, you can do:

```
db.collection('users_donors').doc('users').collection('usersList').where('userType', '==', 'users').get().then(doc => {
  setupUI(user); 
  db.collection('users_donors').doc('donors').collection('donorsList').where('userType', '==', 'donors').get().then(doc => {
    setupUIDonor(user);
  });
});
```

Of, if you're willing to use more modern JavaScript, you can [use `async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
let doc = await db.collection('users_donors').doc('users').collection('usersList').where('userType', '==', 'users').get();
setupUI(user);
 
doc = await db.collection('users_donors').doc('donors').collection('donorsList').where('userType', '==', 'donors').get();
setupUIDonor(user);
```

Comment: I want to display all the details from the user by calling a function which is setupUI(user) but when I logged in donor the first code for collection of users, it always been executed and it cause of error like this Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName')

Comment: That sounds like you're callign `firstName` on a variable that doesn't have a value. I don't see any such call in the code you shared though, so it's gonna be hard to help. --- I recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there drastically increases the chances that someone can help.